# Is there a way to execute a mail merge using excel as data source to word but with multiple recipients and changing email subject using macro?

Tags: excel, vba, mailmerge

I am no expert in macro excel but I am trying to automatically send email to multiple recipients (TO and CC) included per each cell and just separated by semicolon. Additionally, the email subject is also changing if only possible. I have attached here the sample word and excel as data source. Appreciate any help that you could share with me. Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TCc7.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f3xh.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked on here for any posts with examples of vba code stepping through lists of names or users? or vba that works with files? or vba that uses loops?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I already found the solution. Thank you! :)